# input mask for phone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, input-mask

Hello Guys I have no idea how to do it i will have 2 input on my form first will be standart (555) 555-5555
But other input format will be (555) 555-5555/xxxx can type any number instead of x can be 3 numbers,4 numbers it will be manual)

First input I provide with this code below I mentioned

$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999?9-9999");

$("#phone").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

```
if( last.length == 3 ) {
    var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
    var lastfour = move + last;
    var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

    $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
}
```

});

But what to do for second one ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same pattern:

```
.mask("(999) 999-9999/9999")
```

I used 4 placeholders, but you can use more if you need. Use the count of the maximum possible value.